# authenticating and getting notebook list Evernote iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, xcode, evernote

I am trying to implement Evernote, i need to login and get notebook list. i implemented following code ..

```
   ENSession *session = [ENSession sharedSession];
    [[ENSession sharedSession] authenticateWithViewController:self preferRegistration:NO completion:^(NSError *authenticateError) {


    if (authenticateError || !session.isAuthenticated) {
        NSLog(@"Error : %@",authenticateError);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Could not authenticate"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        [self updateButtonsForAuthentication];
    }

}];

- (void)updateButtonsForAuthentication
{
    ENSession *session = [ENSession sharedSession];

    if (session.isAuthenticated) {
        [self showUserInfo];
    } else {

    }
}

- (void)showUserInfo
{
    ENUserStoreClient *userStore = [[ENUserStoreClient alloc]init];
    [userStore fetchUserWithCompletion:^(EDAMUser *  user, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",user);
        NSLog(@"%@",user.username);
    }];
}
```

in Showuserinfo method i am getting EDAMUser as nil and i also want all the notebook list as well.,any help will be great.

Comment: can anyone suggest me where am i going wrong..!?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the:

```
#import <ENSDK/Advanced/ENSDKAdvanced.h>
```

if you haven't read yet, this reference may help you:
https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios/blob/master/Working_with_the_Advanced_(EDAM)_API.md